# EnhancedSeatMapRQ -SOAP - How to get seat availability for all cabins?

Tags: soap, sabre

Is there a way to get seat availability for all cabins available for booking without knowing the aircraft class/fare types?

I checked the service documentation and WSDL file I couldn't find any way to do that.

Sample request

```
<ns6:EnhancedSeatMapRQ >
<ns6:SeatMapQueryEnhanced correlationID="50468727">
    <ns6:RequestType>Payload</ns6:RequestType>
    <ns6:Flight destination="TXL" origin="VIE">
        <ns6:DepartureDate>2016-02-24</ns6:DepartureDate>
        <ns6:Operating carrier="AB">8401</ns6:Operating>
        <ns6:Marketing carrier="AB">8401</ns6:Marketing>
        <ns6:ArrivalDate>2016-02-24</ns6:ArrivalDate>
    </ns6:Flight>
    <ns6:CabinDefinition>
        <ns6:RBD>M</ns6:RBD>
    </ns6:CabinDefinition>
    <ns6:Currency>USD</ns6:Currency>
    <ns6:POS company="AB" multiHost="AB">              
        <ns6:Actual city="HDQ"/>
        <ns6:ClientContext clientType="INTERACT"/>
    </ns6:POS>   
    <ns6:Client>KIOSK</ns6:Client>         
</ns6:SeatMapQueryEnhanced>
```

Response:

As you can see from the response it only returned one cabin (class M) seat availability data.  I have tried different types of requests but I only get one cabin in response.

```
<ns6:EnhancedSeatMapRS >
     <ns4:ApplicationResults status="Complete"/>
     <ns6:SeatMap changeOfGaugeInd="false">
        <ns6:Equipment>320</ns6:Equipment>
        <ns6:Flight destination="TXL" origin="VIE">
           <ns6:DepartureDate>2016-02-24</ns6:DepartureDate>
           <ns6:Operating carrier="AB">8401</ns6:Operating>
           <ns6:Marketing carrier="AB">8401</ns6:Marketing>
        </ns6:Flight>
        <ns6:FareAvailQualifiers accompaniedByInfantInd="false">
           <ns6:TravellerID>2</ns6:TravellerID>
           <ns6:GivenName>QWE</ns6:GivenName>
           <ns6:Surname>QEQP</ns6:Surname>
        </ns6:FareAvailQualifiers>
        <ns6:Cabin firstRow="1" lastRow="30" classLocation="Maindeck" seatOccupationDefault="Free">
           <ns6:CabinClass>
              <ns6:RBD>M</ns6:RBD>
              <ns6:MarketingDescription>PRICE PER SEAT:USD 14.50-USD 30.10</ns6:MarketingDescription>
           </ns6:CabinClass>
           <ns6:Row>
              <ns6:RowNumber>1</ns6:RowNumber>
              <ns6:Seat occupiedInd="false" inoperativeInd="false" premiumInd="false" chargeableInd="true" exitRowInd="false" restrictedReclineInd="false" noInfantInd="false">
                 <ns6:Number>A</ns6:Number>
                 <ns6:Facilities>
                    <ns6:Detail>FrontOfCabin</ns6:Detail>
                 </ns6:Facilities>
                 <ns6:PassengerEntitlementAndPrice entitledInd="true">
                    <ns6:TravellerID>1</ns6:TravellerID>
                    <ns6:Price>
                       <ns6:TotalAmount currencyCode="USD">21.20</ns6:TotalAmount>
                    </ns6:Price>
                 </ns6:PassengerEntitlementAndPrice>
                 <ns6:PassengerEntitlementAndPrice entitledInd="true">
                    <ns6:TravellerID>2</ns6:TravellerID>
                    <ns6:Price>
                       <ns6:TotalAmount currencyCode="USD">21.20</ns6:TotalAmount>
                    </ns6:Price>
                 </ns6:PassengerEntitlementAndPrice>
                 <ns6:Bilateral>
                    <ns6:Characteristic>StandardSeat</ns6:Characteristic>
                 </ns6:Bilateral>
              </ns6:Seat>

              ........

        </ns6:Cabin>
     </ns6:SeatMap>      
  </ns6:EnhancedSeatMapRS>
```

Answer (score 1):

No, the availability of a seat also depends on its class of service. I mean, some seats may be blocked for different classes of service in the same cabin.